# Create a timed loop in Visual Basic that executes every 30 seconds

Tags: vbscript, timer

I need the code below to execute every 30 seconds for a period of nine minutes before moving on. Any ideas?

```
'Begin 9 minute loop

CLEAR CONTENTS
Dim newFIle
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set newFIle = FSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\RECALL\OutlookExport.csv", True, False)
newFIle.Write "Need Data"
newFIle.Close

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Choose File
Set csvOut = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\RECALL\OutlookExport.csv", 8, True)
'Export Messages
For Each email In inbox.Folders.Item(CInt(response)).Items
    csvOut.Write (Chr(34) & email.SenderName & Chr(34) & ",")
    csvOut.Write email.Body
    csvOut.Write (vbNewLine)
Next

'Pause 30 seconds
'Return to "Begin 9 Minute Loop
'Repeat 18 times
'End 9 minute loop (Execute remainder of code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Timer control for VB6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zffx82xt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)